# Run code in background, Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, service, process, background

I would like to call a method every 10 seconds while app is closed. I have read that I have to create a service but I don't understand how. It would send information to a webserver (only personal uses).
Thanks guys!

Comment: Read the documentation on how to create a service.

Comment: We can answer questions for you but we cannot understand for you. There are so many resources available with a quick google search that can teach you how to create a service

Comment: I have read all of them, but I a beginner in this area. If you could provide me instructions how to do it that, that would help me a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't wrote this thread if I know how to make one.

Comment: Why are you *sending* information when your app is closed?

Comment: Have you looked at this ? https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: I want to make an app that uploads the battery life, orientation, rotation etc. of the phone. I took a look at that link, but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send information to your webserver only while the application is running, you can use a thread within unity.

If you want some code to keep running, irrespective of whether or not your app is running, you need service. [This should get you started on how to write a service.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

You can write a small plugin in android native code, and include it's aar/jar in your unity project. Then you may send a message from your unity app via JNI to start the service. Totally depends on how you want to implement it though.

Comment: But if I implement this code in an Andoid Studio project, then how I make it a plugin?

Comment: First, you need to include unity's classes.jar (that's usually the name by default) into your android studio project. This link should help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahGeTNUPLM 
Then use gradle task to export an '.aar' file for you. You should look it up

Comment: Thanks, now I get it how to make a plugin, but my code that I have to run in the background is in Unity. Now I have to convert that into java to call as service?

Comment: Please look into how you can override default unity activity. Then, in your activity, you can start the service. And yes, you have to convert it into java

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way of doing it. You can call a method via `OnApplicationQuit()` and this will run when the app gets closed. I have used this to get changes from my firebase database and send a notification when a child is added. It works. In this case you would have to subscribe to a method and this will run even if the app is closed. Then unsubscribe to this method via the `OnAwake()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
 < https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service>
You have to create a service but probably its very difficult for you.

Comment: You guessed it, I don't even know where to start.